# Reachable points in state-space system

Tags: control-theory

I have the following $(A,B,C)$ state-space sytem:

$$ A =
\begin{bmatrix} 
  -2 &  0 & 0 \\
  -1 & -1 & 2 \\
  -1 &  0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix},\ B = 
\begin{bmatrix}
  0 \\
  1 \\
  0 \\
\end{bmatrix},\ C =
\begin{bmatrix}
  1 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

My question is how do I compute if a point, e.g. $\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 2 & 1\end{bmatrix}^T$, in state space can be reached from $0$ by the choice of an input signal $u(t)$?

Note: the system is not controllable and not observable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compute the controllability

$$
C = 
\begin{bmatrix}
B & AB & A^2B
\end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & -1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Hence only $x_2$ can be controlled thus only states $\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ \alpha \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$ can be reached.